# How to specify Artifact version name in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build and release pipeline in Azure DevOps. The build has **archive** and **publish** steps.

[image]

And then the release picks up the archives to deploy them.

[image]

The build has a parameter where I specify the environment, changing some of the build command arguments. So the build can easily create archives for different environments.

I then have a release for each environment, but I cannot tell which archive belongs to which environment because the version is determined by today's date plus a number.

**Is there a way to specify the version number for an archive or see the archive names in the selection so I can determine which artifacts came from certain build environments?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Version pick list format (the date & number) is taken from the Build Number format, so just add your variable to there:

[image: Build Options page]

Comment: Hello @Shayki Abramczuk. Is there any way to add and use my own variable in the build format number if this variable was not predefined and hence not listed on the variables tab like it mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#variables

The problem is: There is custom format of the version for my project, the version is generated with a PS script while the build pipeline is running. Hence, the version can not be predefined. I think that would be great if you knew that and could expand your answer here.

Comment: @deralbert look in the `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash